# Getting error while running SQL query near "HOUR"

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

query1:

```
SELECT count(*) 
from covips.pool_checkup 
WHERE timeinstance > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
```

```
cursor.execute(query1)
count2 = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print("test ", count2)
```

## ERROR I AM GETTING IS

Error while connecting to PostgreSQL syntax error at or near "HOUR" LINE 2: ...p

```
WHERE timeinstance > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
```

Comment: Plz read the basis of postgres documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query uses MySql syntax for a Postgresql database where there is no `DATE_ADD()` function.
This is the correct syntax:

```
WHERE timeinstance > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour'
```